# Bypass Google Cloud Endpoints ESP for same project but different service on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

We have an app engine service which exposes several APIs which are secured by GCP cloud endpoints, Below is open API definition YAML file just for reference, not the actual one. 
We need to call this service's endpoint from other app engine service, Is there any way to bypass traffic coming from **same project and network** from endpoints ESP?

```
x-google-allow: all
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: 'Sample app'
  version: 0.1.0
host: service-api-server-project-id.appspot.com
schemes:
 - https
paths
  "/metrics":
    get:
      tags:
        - metrics
      summary: Query for  metrics data
      description: Application metrics
      operationId: metrics
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful retrieval of metrics
      security:
        - google_id_token_ic: []
securityDefinitions:
  google_id_token_cor:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "<placeholder>"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "<placeholder>"
    x-google-audiences: "<placeholder>"
```

Note: Same APIs is getting called from outside the project network and GCP which needs to be secured.

Answer (score 0):

After researching and looking through forums and the [architecture diagram](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/about-cloud-endpoints) of how it's set up, I don't think this is possible.

The closest I could find are [dispatch rules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) which might let you connect the two services together, but I think the request would still go through the ESP.

Comment: Thanks, @Oliver, I would explore dispatch rules and see if I can call the other service's API without using any JWT or validation.